# Strange bug with "MessageName[a,b] is not of the form symbol::name ", Debugger & cursor location

Tags: warning-messages, debugging, version-11, usage-messages

Can someone confirm/disconfirm this?

1. Start Mathematica 11, blank notebook, blank init.m
2. Start the Debugger/make sure it is running. It doesn't seem to matter whether you have the Stack and Breakpoints window open too or not. The "Break at ... []" checkboxes can also be checked or not. But uncheck them for now.
3. Enter

   a::b
4. Place the cursor at any of the locations indicated with | in the following:

   a|:|:|b
5. Press shift enter.
6. The message

   > Message::name: Message name MessageName[a,b] is not of the form symbol::name or symbol::name::language.

   will be displayed.

This seems to have other ways of triggering that seem pretty much random, but this method seems reliable.

Do I maybe have some state left from version 10.4 that causes this or does this happen for other people too?

```
$Version
```

> "11.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 28, 2016)"

---

[(FalafelPita)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/46335/falafelpita)

According to the documentation, there are two ways to define a message, which I implement as:

```
ClearAll["sym*"];
(*1*) sym1::name1 = "Message 1.";
(*2*) MessageName[sym2, "name2"] = "Message 2.";
```

When I evaluate these with debugger **OFF**, no errors or messages occur.

When I turn debugger **ON**, restart the kernel, and then evaluate these, the first approach generates an error

> "Message name MessageName[sym1,name1] is not of the
>   form symbol::name or symbol::name::language"

but the second approach does not. I'm running

```
$Version
(*"11.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 13, 2017)"*)
```

Can anyone confirm this? Can anyone see anything incorrect with what I'm doing here? Is this a bug in the debugger?

Maddeningly, the error has been elusively inconsistent. The kernel restart is often NOT necessary to generate the error, but sometimes it has been.

Comment: This problem exists also in 11.1.

Comment: I can confirm it for "10.4.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)". No idea what it means, though.

Comment: I answered this question in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/153041/ before discovering this one.  I don't know if we have a convention against closing older questions as duplicates of newer ones...

Comment: @Itai, you have options: vote to close the unanswered one, transfer your answer to the other one, or (in this case) a mod like me can perform mergers.

Answer (score 3):

Weird.  I can sometimes reproduce this, but only on Windows, and only some of the time.  If I take a cell which suffers from this, copy and paste it, and try again, it will disappear.

This is a bug in the FE.  The debug mode is implemented by wrapping pieces of the cell with an extra `TagBox` so the FE knows where to go when it stops.  In the cases where it goes wrong, there is an extra `TagBox` around "name1", which splits it from the `::`.  You then end up with `MessageName[sym1, name1]` instead of `MessageName[sym, "name1"]` as the input expression.

A possible workaround is to use double quotes around `name` even when using the short form.  I.e., `sym1::"name1"`.  This is never wrong, and it makes sure that "name1" gets interpreted as a string even if it is split off from its double colon.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. I had similar problems with the issue disappearing sometimes after copy and paste or after switching the debugger on and off. It's difficult to pin down. I sent an email to Wolfram about it today.

Answer (score 1):

Response from Wolfram Technical Support: "It does appear that MessageName is not behaving properly when the Debugger is enabled, and I have forwarded an incident report to our developers with the information you provided. The issue appears to be related to the Debugger changing the specific cell type to Debug. "