# Strange behavior of symbol::messageName in debugger

Tags: warning-messages, debugging, message-coding

According to the documentation, there are two ways to define a message, which I implement as:

```
ClearAll["sym*"];
(*1*) sym1::name1 = "Message 1.";
(*2*) MessageName[sym2, "name2"] = "Message 2.";
```

When I evaluate these with debugger **OFF**, no errors or messages occur.

When I turn debugger **ON**, restart the kernel, and then evaluate these, the first approach generates an error

> "Message name MessageName[sym1,name1] is not of the
>   form symbol::name or symbol::name::language"

but the second approach does not. I'm running

```
$Version
(*"11.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 13, 2017)"*)
```

Can anyone confirm this? Can anyone see anything incorrect with what I'm doing here? Is this a bug in the debugger?

Maddeningly, the error has been elusively inconsistent. The kernel restart is often NOT necessary to generate the error, but sometimes it has been.